# Parse JSON on Android device using latest Jackson Parser library

Tags: java, android, json, jackson

Here is example of JSON response str:

```
{"myServiceMethodResult":[{"BoolPropertyOfFooClass":false,"StringPropertyOfFooClass":"tstString", "Bar":[{"BoolPropertyOfBarClass":false,"StringProperyOfBarClass":"tst"}]
}]
}
```

Service is returning List

```
List<Foo> myServiceMethod(){

return new List<Foo> myFooList
}
```

This are the classes:

```
@JsonRootName(value = "myServiceMethodResult")
Class Foo{

public boolean BoolPropertyOfFooClass
public String  StringPropertyOfFooClass


@JsonProperty(value = "Bar")
public List<Bar> myBar;


public boolean getBoolPropertyOfFooClass(){

return BoolPropertyOfFooClass;
}

public void setBoolPropertyOfFooClass(bool value){
this.BoolPropertyOfFooClass = value

}

public String getStringPropertyOfFooClass(){

return StringPropertyOfFooClass;
}

public void setBoolPropertyOfFooClass(String value){
this.StringPropertyOfFooClass = value

}

public List<Bar> myBar() {
        return myBar;
    }

    public void setmyBar(List<Bar> value) {
        this.myBar= value;
    }

}
```

I'm usign Jackson parser and first of all Parsing JSON string to an object is surprising slow (despite a fact that this file is huge (2 MB)

```
  String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(serviceUrl/MethodName, ServiceHandler.POST, json_content_parameters);

       ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
       mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
       JsonNode node = null;
     myFooInstance=  mapper.readValue(new StringReader(jsonStr), new TypeReference<List<Foo>>(){});
```

mapper.readValue is hitting exception myServiceResult does not match expected ('List'). Further more, if I'm using readTree function it takes 5 seconds (but not hittign exception). Is there any better way of getting Object faster,

Further more I'm not able to figure how to map List of Bar objects inside my Foo objects. I'm able to set my properties using this line of code:

```
TypeReference<List<Foo>> typeRef = new TypeReference<List<Foo>>(){};
myInstanceFoo= mapper.readValue(node.traverse(), typeRef);
```

So I Have my List of Foo objects but I'm not able to get List inside of list using something simmilar. Any help about problems with duration, or setting inner List object would be appreciated

Trace:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Root name 'MyMethodResponse' does not match expected ('List') for type [collection type; class java.util.List, contains [simple type, class com.package.Foo]]
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@411dc790; line: 1, column: 2]
```

Comment: First things first, why read the JSON first then reading the tree? Just use `.readValue()` to read directly into POJOs (edit: `mapper.readValue(new StringReader(jsonStr), typeRef)`; even better if you could get the source directly instead of your `makeServiceCall`)

Comment: Actually I'm forced to readTree couse JSON response first element is 
methodNameResponse : {"MyMethodResponse":[{"BoolPropertyOfFooClass

Comment: You could specify this in the question, it is VERY important!

Comment: Can you please paste the full stack trace?

Comment: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Root name 'MyMethodResponse' does not match expected ('List') for type [collection type; class java.util.List, contains [simple type, class com.package.Foo]]
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@411dc790; line: 1, column: 2]

Answer (score 1):

Since it appears that you have the response wrapped in a single-member object instance, you have the option of annotating your `Foo` class with this:

```
@JsonRootName("MyMethodResponse")
```

IMPORTANT: the name is FIXED.

However you are not done yet. You need to configure your `ObjectMapper` to use this annotation:

```
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE);
```

Your have another problem. Namely, your `List<Bar>` has name `myBar` in your POJO, but `Bar` in the produced JSON. You need to annotate your `myBar` field with `@JsonProperty`:

```
@JsonProperty("Bar")
```

Comment: root name MyMethodResponse does not match expected ('List') for type [collection type; class java.util.List, contains [simple type, class Foo]] ?

Comment: Can you edit your question, modify the code with what you have currently (not forgetting the input JSON) and also the full stack trace?

Comment: I edited question, sorry for wrong elements at first

Answer (score 0):

In case Someone stumbles on a same problem I figured it out. To serialize Foo class if JSON is in format

```
{"response":[{"propertyOfFooClass":"something"
}]
}
```

you nedd to Create Root Class that contains list of Foo Class

public class RootWrapper {

```
private List<Foo> foo;

public List<Foo> getFoos() {
    return channels;
}

@JsonProperty("response")
public void setFoos(List<Foo> fooList) {
    this.foo= fooList;
}


RootWrapper mj = mapper.readValue(jsonStr, RootWrapper.class);
```

Cheers